# How to animate an referential SVG background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, vivus

Does exists some way to animate referential background svg with vivus.js? I'm trying to use it. I found this code in the oficial documentation but I don't know if this is possible. Look at the code below:

```
HTML
<section id="svg-bg" class="materiais-topo">
  <!-- some elements here -->
</section>

CSS (SASS)
    .materiais-topo {
      background-color: $green-fluo;
      background-image: url('../images/line-fluo.svg');
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

JS
new Vivus-bg('svg-bg', {
   file: MAIN_URL+'dist/images/line-fluo.svg'
});
```

Someone has any solution? If you know to animate referential background svg without vivus.js let me know.

EDIT: This method only inject SVG file in my div element.

Comment: You show the code that virus.js gave you so, [what have you tried](/help/how-to-ask)? Did you run this to see whether it did, or gave you a start on, what you wanted to achieve for your own site?

Comment: I tryied to do this way, but like I said, not worked. The code that I already used is this above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as far as I know, it's impossible to manipulate a Background SVG with Javascript.

But, you can:

- Use SMIL animations in your SVG (It’s [will not work with MSIE/Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil)), [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/asSSQDVNUICK9f1dSxXZ?p=preview).
- Generate a [data:uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) for every frame with Javascript, and use them as a background-image.

Here an example of SVG SMIL animation:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="100px">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
        <animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 Z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've used keyframes to animate own svg file, something like your example. I don't knew what SVG SMIL animation was, thanks for share!